# Right shifting a paragraph

Tags: paragraphs

Have been working on shifting the `PAR.` part as a shifted paragraph to the right by a certain amount (0.8cm in this instance).  But the whole paragraph is not getting shifted as intended.  Would like to have this functionality in a environment-like way where I can reset `\leftskip` to `0`.

```
\par\noindent
TAG.[1999-DEF8]

\par\noindent
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.8cm}
PAR.Deligne Pierre, Etingof Pavel, et al., 1999; "Quantum Fields and
Strings: A Course for Mathematicians."  Vol. 1-2. With Freed Daniel S.,
Jeffrey Lisa C., Kazhdan David, Morgan John W., Morrison David R.,
Witten Edward.
\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}
```

Comment: you reset the leftskip too early before the paragraph finished, leave a blank line, also you need `%` at the ends of your setlength lines

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I also get a slight indentation for the line starting with `PAR.Deligne`.

Comment: you have not mentioned it but you are using latex, so should not set `\leftskip` directly, or at least, if you do you should reduce `\linewidth` by the same amount and set `\@totalleftmargin` otherwise any `center` or `enumerate` or ... within the region will be misaligned

Comment: the "slight indentation" is the space which is why I said you need a `%` after the setlength so you do not add space there, but you should be using a list environment (look at the `quote` environment for how to do this

Comment: I do not know so much about the details you mention.  Worud it be fine to supply an answer with a more appropriate way to do this?

Comment: Would the modifications mentioned instead of `\leftskip` still apply when using a list ?

Comment: never change `\leftskip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You are resetting the paragraph settings before the paragraph ends so they have no effect. You would need a blank line before the `\setlength`.

You also need `%` at the end of the `\setlength` to avoid adding a space at the beginning of the paragraph.

However you should never set `\leftskip` directly, latex needs to track indentation otherwise `center` or nested lists such as `enumerate` etc will all be confused and mis-aligned.

Such environments should be implemented as lists, so all the indentaion parameters are updated. You could copy `quote` which does this, but indents both sides, but `adjustwidth` is a parameterised version.

I added `parskip` as there should never be explicit `\noindent`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{changepage,parskip}

\begin{document}


TAG.[1999-DEF8]

\begin{adjustwidth}{.8cm}{0cm}
PAR.Deligne Pierre, Etingof Pavel, et al., 1999; "Quantum Fields and
Strings: A Course for Mathematicians."  Vol. 1-2. With Freed Daniel S.,
Jeffrey Lisa C., Kazhdan David, Morgan John W., Morrison David R.,
Witten Edward.
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

That said, this looks like a description list so perhaps you really want

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=nextline]
\item[{TAG.[1999-DEF8]}] 
PAR.Deligne Pierre, Etingof Pavel, et al., 1999; "Quantum Fields and
Strings: A Course for Mathematicians."  Vol. 1-2. With Freed Daniel S.,
Jeffrey Lisa C., Kazhdan David, Morgan John W., Morrison David R.,
Witten Edward.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would to have control upon the amount of right shift to apply. Using `\NewDocumentEnvironment` then use `\list` perhaps . What would a good implementation look like ?

Comment: use enumitem as shown above it has many many options to control all aspects of the spacing start with `[leftmargin=.8cm,newline]` @Ragonese

Comment: I would like to know the alternative considering what you said about not setting `\leftskip`.

Comment: @Ragonese I just gave you an alternative.

Comment: Should I put it as another question about what appropriate commands to shift a paragraph with use of `\leftskip` and without it ? That is something interesting without using lists.

Comment: @Ragonese no, the answer will be to use a list environment. `center`, `verbatim`, `quote`, `quotation`, are _all_ lists internally, that is how latex manages display structures like this.

Comment: Does this mean not to ever shift a paragraph without using lists ?

Comment: @Ragonese why do you care if `adjustwidth` environment in the first example above is internally implemented as a list or not?

Comment: I am just trying to understand the details. With `adjustwidth` I get some vertical spacing between the `TAG.` and `PAR.` on the next line.  I reckon that I want to do something very specific and would be better to have my own implementation, rather than adjusting something else.

Comment: What parameters would I need to change with `\list` without changing `\leftskip` ?

Comment: @Ragonese see enumitem leftmargin for left indent and topsep for vertical space are the main ones you want, probably, but also I suspect you get better markup by making TAG part of the list as in my second example.